# Cookie functions for on mouseleave popup for 30 days is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, cookies

Currently have mouseleave popup working, but want to integrate cookie with it for 30 days.

here is public dev site example: http://www.doityourselfrv.com/services/

This is code I pieced together, but cookie is not working:

```
var cookie_length = 30;

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^s+|s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name) {
         return unescape(y);
      }
   }
}

var show = getCookie("diyrvcooke");
if(show==null || show=="" || 1) {
    setCookie('diyrvcooke','1',cookie_length);
    //show popup here
}
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Jonathan, I am not getting error, just the popup keeps coming up after refresh so no cookie is holding, I included demo link in orig post. Thanks

Comment: @user3923622 you aren't setting the cookie, please see my answer below...the `show` variable is `undefined` not `null`

Comment: @abc123 thank you, i updated the code but no luck. the popup comes after mouseleave with each refresh still

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`if(show==null || show=="" || 1) {`

to

`if(show == null || show == "") {`

In your code you're checking for 1 then setting the cookie as 1 so it won't be set, or if it's somehow set, will stay set...

Comment: no need for the last part at all... just `if(show == null || show == "") {` since it will expire in 30 days also show is undefined not null..

Comment: Thanks, I changed however cookie still not holdling, please see demo site in orig post I added.

Comment: @user3923622 There's no javascript on that page related to cookies

Comment: elzi, starts at line 78 on view source

Comment: @user3923622 looks like a caching issue: https://s3.amazonaws.com/anagram-ss/PR5KQdonkPuxc.png

Answer (score 0):

## [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GS1vZMJj4TnWpU9VAppB?p=preview)

**JS**

```
var cookie_length = 30;

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays===null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
   var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
   for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
      x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
      y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
      x=x.replace(/^s+|s+$/g,"");
      if (x==c_name) {
         return unescape(y);
      }
   }
}

var show = getCookie("diyrvcooke");
//show will be undefined the first time before a cookie is set.
if(show===undefined) {
    setCookie('diyrvcooke','1',cookie_length);
    //show popup here
    alert('popup here');
}
```